# Precision when dividing by large integers

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that computes e<sup>x</sup> (for the first 10 terms) given an integer `x.

The series expansion for e<sup>x</sup> is given by

```
1 + x + x2/2! + x3/3! + x4/4! + ....
```

The function itself was fairly easy to write, but I can't seem to understand Haskell type rules for division, i.e I want to divide an integer by a larger integer and get  a floating-point result:

Here is what I have so currently

```
_eToX :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a
_eToX x 0 = 1.0
_eToX x 1 = x
_eToX x n = ( fromIntegral(x^n) / fromIntegral(factorial n) ) + _eToX x (n - 1)
```

What I am doing above here makes sense to me, compute two integer results (`x^n` and `factorial n`) then evaluate them in a Floating point context using `fromIntegral` and `/`. This function however returns this error:

```
    1. Could not deduce (a ~ Integer)
    from the context (Fractional a, Integral a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 _eToX :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a
      at /run-r4AWbVU9Fyph0OVhK3Dm/solution.hs:9:10-50
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            _eToX :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a
          at /run-r4AWbVU9Fyph0OVhK3Dm/solution.hs:9:10
    In the return type of a call of `factorial'
    In the second argument of `(/)', namely `factorial n'
    In the first argument of `(+)', namely `(x ^ n / factorial n)'

    2. No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `f'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Double)
    In the expression: f
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `f $ map (read :: String -> Double) $ lines inputdata'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `map show $ f $ map (read :: String -> Double) $ lines inputdata'
```

I am running the function with this main function:

```
main = do
   n <- readLn :: IO Int -- n doesnt really matter here because of getContents
   inputdata <- getContents
   mapM_ putStrLn $ map show $ f $ map (read :: String -> Double) $ lines inputdata
```

Comment: You can use `Rational` then you don't need fromIntegral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type:

```
_eToX :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a
```

doesn't make sense.  You want the first argument and result to be `Fractional`, but the second argument, corresponding to the sequence position, should be `Integral`.  Change the type to:

```
_eToX :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

Now there's a different error, arising from a missing `Integral` instance because of `fromIntegral (x^n)`.  ghci shows

```
Prelude> :t (^)
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
```

So it's not necessary to even use `fromIntegral` here, as the output is already the correct type.  The final function is:

```
_eToX :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
_eToX x 0 = 1.0
_eToX x 1 = x
_eToX x n = ( (x^n) / fromIntegral(factorial n) ) + _eToX x (n - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Haskell is very unlike most functional languages so I am having a little trouble with Typeclasses. I still seem to get an error relating to the factorial call; but I'll work through it on my own.

Comment: It may be related to your factorial definition.  I was using `factorial n = product [1..n]`, which requires an additional `Enum` constraint, but is easy.

Comment: My defintion is `factorial :: Integer -> Integer`, `factorial n = product [1..n]`

Comment: I thought about what you said about a Enum constraint and came up with this: `factorial :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a` which seems to typecheck correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: that makes sense.  Your original `factorial` constrained the input to `Integer`, where in `_eToX` it was called at type `Integral b => b`.  That would work if you changed the `b` type parameter to `Integer` in the type of `_eToX`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are probably looking for.

```
eToX :: Integral a => Double -> a -> Double
eToX x 0 = 1
eToX x 1 = 1 + x
eToX x n = x^^n / (fromIntegral $ factorial n) + eToX x ( n - 1)
```

`(^^) :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`

You didn't want `n` and `x` to be the same.  See how that power function does it.

Oh, and your equation was wrong for `n = 1` you should have `1 + x`

Answer (score 0):

Is your `f` the given `_eToX`? your _eToX takes two arguments but you apply f to only one.
This is fine as long as you only want a a partial application.

Concerning the error messages you should check the following:

What is the type of your factorial it seems to be something that has an Integer as an result and not something that implements the Typclasses `Integral` and `fractional`

You added a type annotation for your read function, s.t. it returns a `Double` Which is not an instance of `Integral`. But your `f` seems to take something as an argument which is an instance of `Integral`.